# On a finite algebra on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This should be a famous question on a (finite) algebra.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}=\left\{A \subset \mathbb{N} : \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\#(A\cap \{1,2,\ldots,n\})}{n} \text{ exists}\right\}.
\end{align*}
Here, we denote by $\#$ the counting measure.

Why $\mathcal{F}$ is a (finite) algebra on $\mathbb{N}$?

That is, I would like to know how to prove $A \cup B \in \mathcal{F}$ provided that $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$.

This should be equivalent to show that the cesaro mean $\{(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^n\textbf{1}_{A \cap B}(k)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges if the cesaro means $\{(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^n\textbf{1}_{A}(k)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^n\textbf{1}_{B}(k)\}_{n=1}^\infty$. However, I don't feel that this claim holds true.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you four your comment.  After all, $ \mathcal{F} $ is not an algebra? I'll look the link (I'm not sure if this is the answer right away.).

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ is not an algebra.  See also the construction in [this answer](/a/906479).

Comment: @user10354138 Ah. I could not find this answer. Thank you.